# Does the more command in Windows only affect output, or command execution as well?

Tags: windows-xp, visual-studio, processing, cmd.exe, more

I am running a software build in Visual Studio 2005 on Win XP via the command line (devenv.exe /rebuild).  I piped it though more and then realized I didnt want to have to baby sit it so I quit more with Q.  Now I see nothing in the CMD window.  Does the command run as normal, and more just buffers and displays STDOUT, and it will continue to run despite more being quit, or is this build now never going to complete?

Comment: I can say that in this case the build appears to have completed successfully, but it would still be interesting to hear some answers and specifics.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question!

The process you have piped into MORE will continue to run until its natural completion or until you kill it. Here's a test to show it:

Open 2 cmd windows.

At prompt one run:
ping -n 120 127.0.0.1 | more

At prompt two run:
tasklist | findstr /I ping

The ping will run for approx 120 seconds, but with a standard cmd window will reach a page-full in less time than that (adjust the ping command accordingly).

You can show in prompt two that PING carries on running whether or not you kill MORE with "Q". It's only by killing off the PING command completely with ctrl+C, or by waiting the full 50 seconds, that ping is stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `more` buffers and the process continues to run even if you don't scroll the output.

If you exit `more` early, though, `nonexistent pipe` errors *do* appear in some circumstances. This appears to not impact execution and is likely due to the test method used.

---

We can test with a simple batch file:

```
@echo off
for /l %%a in (1,1,100) do echo %%a
msg * done
```

By piping that into `more`, it is apparent that the process continues to execute regardless of whether `more` is scrolled or not: we see the `done` message without advancing `more`.

However, if we increase the runtime like so, and exit `more` with `q` mid-command:

```
@echo off
for /l %%a in (1,1,10000) do echo %%a
msg * done
```

We get a lot of error messages:

```
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
```

The messagebox still appears. Retesting with a simple C# or C program does not replicate this behaviour. My guess is that if the stream is already open, it will proceed as normal (no output) - but the `echo` command used in the tests above actually try to open the stream fresh every time, and once the pipe destination is closed that is no longer possible.